# Changing range of variables netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a variable:

```
ask group [set means-one groupmeans + resources-agent ]
```

I want to ask netlogo to constrain the variable between 1 to 99.
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to simplify Alan's first answer to remove the if statements:

You could do:

```
ask group [set means-one (max (list 1 (min (list 99 groupmeans + resources-agent))) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not entirely clear.  What do you mean by "change the range"? If you mean to clip extreme values, you can do it like this:

```
to-report clip [#x #min #max]
  if (#x < #min) [report #min]
  if (#x > #max) [report #max]
  report #x
end
```

Then you can `ask turtles [set means-one clip means-one 1 99]`.  Otoh, if you actually want to rescale all existing values linearly into your new range, you could do the following:

```
to rescale-all-means-one
  let _newmin 1
  let _newmax 99
  let _newrange (_newmax - _newmin)
  let _lst [means-one] of turtles
  let _min min _lst
  let _max max _lst
  let _range (_max - _min)
  ask turtles [
    let _scale (means-one - _min) / _range
    let _scaled (_newmin + _scale * _newrange)
    set means-one _scaled
  ]
end
```